# How to start a Rails application using Upstart, Unicorn and PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, upstart, foreman

I use the following Upstart script to start the Rails application at boot time (as a service). It works fine with SQLite as database engine. I am on Ubuntu 10.04 and I use Unicorn.

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on starting rcS
respawn

env RVM_SHELL=/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell
env RUBY_VERSION="1.9.2"
env APP_ROOT=/home/pillango/pillango/case-management-database
env RAILS_ENV=production

script
  chdir $APP_ROOT
  $RVM_SHELL $RUBY_VERSION -c 'RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV foreman start'
end script
```

I switched to Postgres (8.4). The application runs fine when I lunch it from the console with the command `RAILS_ENV=production foreman start` but I can't get it to start at boot time, like it did when I was using SQLite.

Any idea of to do to make it work with Postgres at boot time?